# Is the sentence correct without an article?

Tags: articles

In the following sentence:

> I would go there by 'a' tractor.

What if I omit the article 'a'? Would the meaning change if I omit 'a' from the sentence?

Comment: 'By tractor' says that that is the method of transport you would choose (similarly 'by bus', 'by train'). You might use an article to refer to a particular vehicle, but then 'on' or 'in' would be more usual  - 'go there on a tractor', 'on the bus', 'in the car'.

Comment: If I use the article 'a', then it shows a particular vehicle?

Comment: Both _a_ and _the_ imply a particular vehicle.

Comment: It is said that 'the' is used for specificity and for this reason, it is called definite article.

Comment: That is correct. _A_ particular tractor (that you haven't mentioned before), or _the_ tractor that you own, or that you have mentioned  previously.

Comment: I really sometime think that it is safe not to use any article to be on a safe side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't need an article in this context. When you use "by" in this way you are speaking about a *mode* of transport, rather than a vehicle as a noun, so it does not have an article. You can say *by bus, by train, by car, by plane, by bicycle* etc.

If you use an article it will be understood to be a noun. For example, you said "*a bus*" or even "*the bus*" you are referring to a specific vehicle. "By bus" refers to the *bus service*, which could be any number of vehicles in rotation. You can also say "by *air*", "*by sea*" or "*by land*" when referring to a choice of travel.

This isn't unusual, for example, we do the same for means of communication. "Email" is a countable noun - you can say you received *an email*. But when referring to the means of communication you can say "*I communicate by email*".

If you wanted to refer to the vehicle, the idiomatic way to do this is to switch the preposition "by" to "on". You could then say "*I would go there on a tractor*". A notable exception to this rule is "on foot" which is an idiomatic way of saying "by walking".

Comment: How by 'the' bus or by 'a' bus is referring to a specific vehicle? I have read that 'the' is used for specificity

Comment: @jai If you say "I crossed the country on a bus", it explicitly states that you took the entire trip on one bus.  If you instead say "I crossed the country by bus", it leaves open the possibility that you maybe had to transfer to multiple different buses at various terminals.

Comment: Then why the article 'a' is called as indefinite article?

Comment: @jai things are further complicated because people tend to talk about "a bus" and "the bus" in terms of bus routes rather than specific vehicles. As a native British English speaker I would take "I travelled there on a bus" to mean you took one bus (but there might have been more than one bus or bus route available and I don't know which one of those you took), "I travelled there on the bus" to mean you took one bus and I know which bus or route from context (either there is only one or you've talked about it), and "I travelled there by bus" to mean you used one or more buses to get there.

Comment: @jai "The bus" almost means "this/that bus".  "A bus" and "the bus" both talk about just one bus (because it's "the bus", not "the bus**es**").  However "the bus" is more specific than "a bus".  In case you know some Japanese, "the bus" almost means "この/その/あの　バス", but "a bus" almost means "あるバス".

Comment: "The" almost means "this/that/these/those".  "The" can be used with one or more than one.  However, "a" is always used with one.  "A" almost means "one", but "a" *also* almost means "any".  The meaning of "a" is in between "one" and "any".

Comment: @Muzer IMO "I took the train" can mean any train and possibly more than one, and I don't see why "went by bus" should be different

Comment: "by" essentially puts you into a context where the article is irrelevant. If you are going to use an article, you wouldn't use "by" at all, but "in"/"on"/"with"'etc as appropriate.

Comment: @jai The indefinite article can still point to a specific thing. For example, if someone said "I have a dog", that means they have one dog. There are many dogs, so the indefinite article is correct, but they own one specific dog. The can then go on to talk about "my dog". When I said "a bus" means a specific bus, I mean it refers to a vehicle. "I caught a bus" means you got on one bus. "I got *the* bus" means there is only one possible bus and you got on it. But you're not talking about vehicles here, you're talking about the *mode of transport* - don't use an article.

Comment: Isn't it safe not to use any article to be on a safer side?

Comment: @jai Not really - if you omit the article when using the vehicle as a noun, it will be wrong. For example, "I got on bus" would be grammatically incorrect without the article. It depends on how you are using it - if you are referring to the vehicle as a noun, use an article; if you are referring to it as a means of transport, don't.